# How to add foreign key to a usera.table from a userb.table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am new to Oracle, I have tried to add a foreign key `"SupplyMGR"."SUPPLIES"`  to an `"OrderMGR"."USEDIN"`.

But I am getting the following error

> ALTER TABLE "SupplyMGR"."SUPPLIES" ADD CONSTRAINT OrderMGR_fk FOREIGN KEY (ORDERNO) REFERENCES "OrderMGR"."USEDIN"(ORDERNO)
>
> Error report
> ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
> 00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"
> *Cause:
> *Action:

Code:

```
ALTER TABLE "SupplyMGR"."SUPPLIES" 
    ADD CONSTRAINT OrderMGR_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (ORDERNO) REFERENCES "OrderMGR"."USEDIN"(ORDERNO);
```

All tables created.
**"SupplyMGR"."SUPPLIES" Table**

```
+-----+--------------+---------------+-------------------+-----+-----+
| SID | SDESCRIPTION | AMOUNTINSTOCK | SEPTUSAGE         |STYPE|ORDERNO
+-----+--------------+---------------+-------------------+-----+-----+
|   1 | desc2        |             3 |                20 | 200 |
|   2 | desc1        |           300 |                10 |  30 |
+-----+--------------+---------------+-------------------+-----+-----+
```

**"OrderMGR"."USEDIN" Table**

```
+---------+--------------+----------+--------------+-------+---------+
| ORDERNO | SDESCRIPTION | SUPPLIES | QUANTITYUSED | STYPE | BIGJOBS |
+---------+--------------+----------+--------------+-------+---------+
|    9001 | desc2        |       20 |           10 | type1 | Bigjob1 |
|    9002 | desc1        |       30 |           20 | type2 | Bigjob2 |
+---------+--------------+----------+--------------+-------+---------+
```

Kindly help

Comment: can we get the DDL (or subset of it) for the 2 tables so we can replicate the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it *works*. I don't have your users nor tables so I used my own (simplified, though).

First user:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "MIKE"
SQL>
SQL> create table usedin (orderno number primary key);

Table created.

SQL> grant references on usedin to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

Second user (who references the table):

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL>
SQL> create table supplies
  2    (sid     number primary key,
  3     orderno number);

Table created.

SQL> alter table supplies add constraint ordermgr_fk foreign key (orderno)
  2  references mike.usedin (orderno);

Table altered.

SQL>
```